# convert a string into a dictionary given the format of the output in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I was able to use google api finance but it stopped working today so i have been forced to find an alternative.

Im trying to implement google finance module and below is my attempt at it

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
import time
import ast  

y = json.dumps(getQuotes('YHOO'), indent=2)

print y
print type(y)
print len(y)
price = y[275]
print price



##where i wanna be able to update the stock price 
#while True:

    #time.sleep(3)
```

Then i get the following output,

```
[
  {
    "Index": "NASDAQ", 
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "32.58", 
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2016-03-03T11:54:19Z", 
    "LastTradePrice": "32.58", 
    "LastTradeTime": "11:54AM EST", 
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Mar 3, 11:54AM EST", 
    "StockSymbol": "YHOO", 
    "ID": "658890"
  }
]
<type 'str'>
292
[
```

I know that if i slice it as in `y= y[1:len(y)-1]` and get rid of `[]` of the original output, it's in the `dict` format.
Not sure where to go from here. (I know that if i just copy the output after the slicing and assign it to a new variable, it's stored as a dict )

Comment: `getQuotes()` returns the data as a python object.  Why are you dumping it to a json string just to try and convert that string back to python objects?

Comment: I wanted the output to be a dict so i can just pick out what i want by referencing keys

Comment: `getQuotes` returns a list of dictionaries.  Just do `getQuotes('YHOO')[0]['StockSymbol']`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `getQuotes` returns a list containing one item which is a dictionary. If you want to get just that dictionary without the list, then extract it using indexing:

```
my_dict = getQuotes('YHOO')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `getQotes()` returns a `list` with a `dict` inside, there is no reason to jsonify it first.

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json

yhoo = getQuotes('YHOO')[0]
jsonyhoo = json.dumps(yhoo, indent=2)
assert type(yhoo) is dict
assert type(jsonyhoo) is str
```

As an aside, you don't need to run:

```
someString[1:len(someString)-1]
```

You can simply do:

```
someString[1:-1]
```

for the same effect.